# Ajax cross domain script request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which is attempting to eval some Javascript returned from an HTTPS URL. I am running the code locally, on localhost:8080 but the ajax request isn't returning the script, it's coming back as undefined.

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'script',
    url: 'https://mysite.io/live?action=isAvailable',
    success: init,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
        failure();
    },
    timeout: 2000,
    cache: false
});

function init(data) {
    var isAvailable = undefined;
    eval(data);
    if (isAvailable) {
        chatAvailable();
    } else {
        chatUnavailable();
    }
}
```

This is the response when I visit the URL in Chrome:
[https://mysite.io/live?action=isAvailable]:

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-language: en-US
content-type: text/javascript;charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 05:59:25 GMT
p3p: CP="NON CUR OTPi OUR NOR UNI"
x-old-content-length: 23
transfer-encoding: chunked

Response body:
var isAvailable = true;

Any ideas why this isn't working when I run this code on my local machine at  [http://localhost:8080]?

Comment: url is not working timeout

Comment: modern browsers such as chrome, no longer allow cross site ajax calls. basically the domains have to match. couple solutions: 1. pass a header that says allow cross site scripts on certain domains, 2. use jsonp

Comment: Why not just dynamically insert a script tag and let the browser loaded it for you, execute it for you and tell you when it's done?   [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS on your server. [Here](http://enable-cors.org/) is a good resource for enabling CORS.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://mysite.io/live?action=isAvailable?callback=?',
        success: init,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, msg) {
            failure();
        },
        timeout: 2000,
        cache: false
    });
```